# How to step forward to next 'file' from a breakpoint in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to understand the workflow of a project, and want to instrument on each file that is called.

I've tried to use definition/reference to set breakpoint manually, but it's a huge project that it might miss something this way.

I've also used the step forward button in Visual Studio but it just jumps to the very next line, which makes it impossible to trace the entire project.

Is there something that you can jump to the next file, instead of the next line? Or is there some other tools that could help me understand the flow of the codes?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. There is no "flow of the files".

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, how someone describes something might not necessarily make sense to you, but if it makes sense to them, it's a fair way to describe their question.

Comment: If you simply read the code and use `Go To Definition F12` and `Go To Implmenetation Ctl+F12` it will be clear what methods are defined in separate files.

Comment: There isn't a "next file".  Files do not have an execution order.

Comment: @KyleMit - It doesn't hurt to point out parts that don't make sense based on non-standard terminology or unclear descriptions because it brings that to a poster's attention and they can adjust (as they did here, changing "files" -> "codes") and learn. As you know, posts are for the benefit of the community, not just OP. My comment was not meant to be taken in a condescending tone, although we lose some intent when communicating through text. I definitely *did not* mean "this question doesn't have value because I don't understand this part".

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, that's totally fair, and it definitely is a balancing act to get long term community value from quality posts while also helping individual users get a better understanding of the terms and concepts they're searching for. But I'd also consider a comment that merely states "This doesn't make sense" as relatively unwelcoming, if I was forced to treat it as a boolean.  It is hard to search for answers when you don't already know the words to describe it, and there's enough other information in the post like "jumps to the very next line" that do make some sense

Comment: Either way, I presume best intentions all around and think there's some value in pointing out what routes might not make sense, and more still in pointing out what options do.

Comment: @KyleMit - that is also totally fair. It's a hard balancing act indeed when addressing new users and those with less experience. Jon Skeet had a great article on it: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/ (I think that's the one, I could be wrong - just quickly skimmed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do is:

> **Step *Into* Code** with <kbd>F11</kbd>

Instead of:

> **Step *Over* Code** with <kbd>F10</kbd>

Stepping into code will move into the next method being called.  Often times this is located in another file but it doesn't have to be by definition.

[image: Screenshot]

**Further Reading**:

- [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)
- [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @user6219476 - as others have said, there is no "next file". Files do not have an execution order.  But it sounds like KyleMit has given you what you're actually looking for - the ability to "step into" the next called function (regardless of what source file that function happens to be in).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to understand the workflow of a project. Though it requires some manual configuration to monitor an ASP.NET application.